# Android : 6 Getting file name using content resolver

Tags: android, file, filenames, android-contentresolver

DocumentFile.fromSingleUri() and getName() ,if i use this can i able to get the file name in andorid 6 , i am facing this issue in android 6,is there any solution to get  file name of downloaded file using content resolver?

Comment: `DocumentFile` is from the support library. Current versions work back to API Level 15.